# Inserting data from an array of objects into Postgres table from Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postgresql

So I've been trying to work with this JSON data and Postgres all day and cannot figure out what I'm doing to cause this.

This is what my data set looks like, the full set is about 1000 objects:

```
{
    avgHighPrice: null,
    highPriceVolume: 0,
    avgLowPrice: 1633,
    lowPriceVolume: 1,
    id: '267'
  },
  {
    avgHighPrice: 3581,
    highPriceVolume: 1,
    avgLowPrice: 3501,
    lowPriceVolume: 290,
    id: '269'
  },
  {
    avgHighPrice: 800,
    highPriceVolume: 1,
    avgLowPrice: null,
    lowPriceVolume: 0,
    id: '272'
  }, ...
```

I am trying to add the id, avgHighPrice, avgLowPrice to the following Postgres table

```
CREATE TABLE ticker_summary (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY references items,
    open_high INT,
    open_low INT,
    high_price INT,
    low_price INT,
    high_vol INT,
    low_vol INT,
    last_update INT
);
```

I am doing this from Node using the following code

```
await db.query("INSERT INTO ticker_summary (id, open_high, open_low) SELECT x.id, x.avgHighPrice, x.avgLowPrice FROM json_to_recordset($1) AS x (avgHighPrice INT, highPriceVolume INT, avgLowPrice INT, lowPriceVolume INT, id INT);", [JSON.stringify(array)]);
```

Where `array` is the array of objects.

When I do this the code successfully executes but it only inserts the id values and everything else is null which I assume means it is not matching the fields with the defined names but I have no idea why.

Any ideas?

Postgres Test debug code

```
INSERT INTO ticker_summary (id, open_high, open_low) 
SELECT x.id,
x.avgHighPrice,
x.avgLowPrice
FROM json_to_recordset('[{"avgHighPrice":153,"highPriceVolume":61308,"avgLowPrice":151,"lowPriceVolume":11252,"id":"2"},{"avgHighPrice":194920,"highPriceVolume":1,"avgLowPrice":182001,"lowPriceVolume":1,"id":"6"},{"avgHighPrice":187121,"highPriceVolume":4,"avgLowPrice":178642,"lowPriceVolume":2,"id":"10"}]') 
AS x (avgHighPrice INT, highPriceVolume INT, avgLowPrice INT, lowPriceVolume INT, id INT);
```

I need the 3 values extracted from each object in the array and but into its own row in Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding double quotes for the extracted columns work.

See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) whx

```
SELECT x."id",
x."avgHighPrice",
x."avgLowPrice"
FROM json_to_recordset('[{"avgHighPrice":153,"highPriceVolume":61308,"avgLowPrice":151,"lowPriceVolume":11252,"id":"2"}
  ,{"avgHighPrice":194920,"highPriceVolume":1,"avgLowPrice":182001,"lowPriceVolume":1,"id":"6"}
  ,{"avgHighPrice":187121,"highPriceVolume":4,"avgLowPrice":178642,"lowPriceVolume":2,"id":"10"}]') 
AS x ("avgHighPrice" INT, "highPriceVolume" INT, "avgLowPrice" INT, "lowPriceVolume" INT, "id" INT);
```

| id | avgHighPrice | avgLowPrice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 153 | 151 |
| 6 | 194920 | 182001 |
| 10 | 187121 | 178642 |

> ```
> SELECT 3
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CTK6Vp_Y)

Comment: because https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Looks like the case sensitivity required the quotes in this case. Thanks for the help!